# Django: Accessing kwargs using HttpResponseRedirect(reverse()) in passed view

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, url, httpresponse

I am trying to access the kwargs passed through HttpResponseRedirect() in a success view. The key is present in the kwarg dict, but the value is not. Why is this?

Views:

```
class UploadView(View):

    paneluploadform = PanelUploadForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        paneluploadform = self.paneluploadform()
        context = {'paneluploadform': paneluploadform}
        return render(request, 'results/upload.html', context)


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        paneluploadform = self.paneluploadform(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if paneluploadform.is_valid():
            panel_name = paneluploadform.upload()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(
                    reverse('results:success',
                    kwargs={'panel_name': panel_name})
                )


        context = {'paneluploadform': paneluploadform}
        return render(request, 'results/upload.html', context)


def success(request, *args, **kwargs):

    return render(request, 'results/success.html')
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^upload/$', UploadView.as_view(), name='upload'),
    url(r'^upload/successful-(?P<panel_name>)', success, name='success')
]
```

In my `success.py` view when i `print(kwargs)` the output is `{'panel_name': ''}`

But my url is /localhost/upload/successful-panelnameientered

Why doesn't `kwargs ={'panel_name': 'panelnameientered'}`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure, but I think you should be using `re_path` and also you didn't set a pattern to match what is after `successful-`. so it should be like:

```
re_path(r'^upload/successful-(?P<panel_name>[a-z]+)', success)
```

Comment: `re_path` is an alias for `url` (or vice versa), but you're right about the pattern itself.

Comment: The redirect works with url/re_path, but kwargs still doesn't have my panel_name in it? Why do I need [a-z]+ in the url also, if having (?P<panel_name>) inserts the panel name into my url?

Comment: thanks @DanielRoseman for the aclaration. I would say because on your example `panel_name` is matching against an empty regex (`''`), but if you set `[a-z]+`, then it will get everything after `successful-`

Comment: ok thanks! But why is panel_name not in my kwargs in the success view?

Comment: from what I understand `panel_name` is there, but empty isn't it? with the new regex it should be there with the correct value.

Comment: when i change the urls to re_path(r'^upload/successful-(?P<panel_name>[a-z]+)', success), and enter the form again, in my success view it is still kwargs={'panel_name'=''}

Comment: maybe change `[a-z]+` to `.+`

Comment: Hi - I had the ) in the wrong place! It is now corrected thank you very much. Why does this mean that the panel_name is now in kwargs? What does the [a-z+] do to this dict?

Comment: after the `>` starts the part of the regex that it should actually match, so if you don't really understand what `[a-z]+` I would suggest learning a quick guide on regex, it is very helpful. Glad I helped you.